# MySQL group replication error: Transaction rollback (3101)

Tags: mysql, group-replication

I've been looking for a solution to the following issue. I have a group replication up and running on 3 MySQL nodes:

```
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.replication_group_members;
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+----------------------------+
| CHANNEL_NAME              | MEMBER_ID                            | MEMBER_HOST | MEMBER_PORT | MEMBER_STATE | MEMBER_ROLE | MEMBER_VERSION | MEMBER_COMMUNICATION_STACK |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+----------------------------+
| group_replication_applier | 29e78953-45e6-11ec-9059-525400d93145 | 192.168.1.1 |        3306 | ONLINE       | PRIMARY     | 8.0.28         | XCom                       |
| group_replication_applier | bba55f3b-aea7-11ec-89c4-525400e512c6 | 192.168.1.3 |        3306 | ONLINE       | PRIMARY     | 8.0.28         | XCom                       |
| group_replication_applier | f984f3b4-aea2-11ec-a040-525400eeefc6 | 192.168.1.2 |        3306 | ONLINE       | PRIMARY     | 8.0.28         | XCom                       |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+----------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, in some occasions (not always?), I get the error on executing queries:

```
Transaction rollback: 3101 Plugin instructed the server to rollback the current transaction.
```

When I'm looking at the MySQL error logs, I can't find any indicator why this occurred? Even, when I execute the query by hand that is reported by my error catching, it succeeds?

What is the cause of this error? And most important, how can I prevent it from happening?

*Could it perhaps be caused by network latency? 1 of the 3 MySQL nodes is running in a different data-center to be geographically redundant*

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem.
Using group-replication with 3 masters and a round-robin proxy to read/write into all 3 databases.

When I remove the round-robin and let it write to 1 database the problem disappears.

However, this basically leaves me with a master-replica-replica configuration.
group-replication-auto-increment-increment=7 {default}
so it can't be a primary key collision which my first gut thought.